# Vue.js: How To Make A Request On Behalf Of A Component From The Interceptor?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, interceptor

In my Vue app, I have a response interceptor:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (config) {
        return config;
    }, error => {
        if (error.response.status !== 401) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        }

        if (error.response.status === 401 && error.response.data.message === 'Token Expired') {
            this.store.dispatch('auth/refreshToken').then(aToken => {
                var config = error.config;
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + aToken;

                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    axios.request(config).then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        resolve(response);
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        reject(error);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

...where I am refreshing the token and making the last (intercepted) request again with the new token.

But the problem is, say I have a component, `Product.vue`, where I am making a request to the `/products` endpoint when the component mounts. I am storing all the products in a `products` data variable of that component. Imagine the user is in the `/dashboard` route now. He went for a sip of coffee and by the time he comes back the token is already expired. He visits the `/products` route, the response is 401, so the interceptor intercepts that response, updates the token, and then attempts to make the last failed request with the new token.

But this new request was not performed from the `Product` component. It was performed from the interceptor, where I don't have access to the `Product` component. Hence, although the request was successful, my response data are lost and the end-user will see nothing in the view because the `products` variable is empty.

Is there a way to track which component performed the request and remount it in the interceptor? I tried `$router.push('/products')` but vue throws an exception stating that navigation to current route not allowed.

Or, is there some way to handle the promise that is being returned from the interceptor in the Product component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is keep the promise chain running. At the moment you're losing it by not returning the *dispatch* promise.

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(success => success, error => {
  if (error.response.status === 401 && error.response.data.message === 'Token Expired') {
    // return the new promise
    // not sure what "this" is or why "store" is in it but hey, it's your code
    return this.store.dispatch('auth/refreshToken').then(token => {
      axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
      return axios.request(error.config)            
    })
  }
  return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

---

To explain, Axios' response interceptors insert themselves into the promise chain created by requests. Think of them like adding an extra `.then()` onto the end of the request before your calling code receives the data...

```js
return axios.request({ ... })
  .then(successInterceptor)
  .catch(errorInterceptor)
```

In your code, you  don't care about successful responses so you just return the original response

```
success => success
```

Your error interceptor then checks for expired token responses and **returns a new promise** that starts with renewing the token then repeating the original request (see [*Promise chaining*](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)).

If the response error is not for an expired token, you just maintain the error state by returning a [rejected promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject). If you don't do this, the rejected promise becomes a successful one which would be very confusing to your calling code .

Comment: Thanks a lot @Phil Don't worry about `this`. `this` is just pointing to my custom `Auth` class where I put the interceptor method. Your solution worked :) Could you do me a favor? Could you please explain the hierarchy of the events going on here? Lots of return statements confusing me. Why did we return the `axios.request()`?